# We are upgrading our application to java6 and an xsl transform that worked with java 5 now returns an empty document

Tags: java, xslt, upgrade, java-6

Has anybody seen anything like this before?  I will post the xsl and xml if I have to but I would have to take sensitive data out of it.

The code used to handle the XSL transformation:

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new DOMSource( xslDoc)); 
DOMResult domresult = new DOMResult(); 
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(xmlDoc), domresult); 
Node node = domresult.getNode(); 
resultDoc = (Document) node;
```

Comment: We need more information like the code handling the XSL transformation. It probably is this piece of code that needs to be updated!

Comment: TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new DOMSource(
     xslDoc));

   DOMResult domresult = new DOMResult();
   transformer.transform(new DOMSource(xmlDoc), domresult);

   Node node = domresult.getNode();
   resultDoc = (Document) node;

Comment: Are you really handling `Node`s or are you actually handling `File`s ?

Comment: There is no file s in the code....this transform code works on other xsl transforms we give it just this one is failing now since we updated to java6 and it worked on java5.  I am wondering the difference between the xsl transformation on java5 vs java6.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen it going blank. For JAVA6 (also compatible with 1.5), I have the following code that is working, the difference seems to on TransformerFactory used.

```
private DocumentBuilderFactory factory;
private DocumentBuilder builder;
private Transformer xformer;

//presetup - needs to be done just once
factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

//Transform the file
Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
String oFileName = "output.xml";
File oFile = new File(outputDirectory + "/" + oFileName); 
Result result = new StreamResult(oFile);
xformer.transform(source, result);
```

Does this correct your issue?